# Add hours or days to a timestamp in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a timestamp which in which I want to add 48 hours or 2 days. How can I add?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
void main() {
  var date1 = DateTime.utc(2020, 10, 28, 0, 0, 0);
  date1 = date1.add(Duration(days: 2));
  print(date1);
}
```

`date1 = date1.add(Duration(days: 2));  //days`

`date1 = date1.add(Duration(hours: 48)); //hours`

Answer (score 1):

The `DateTime` instance can be created from two methods -

- fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch
- fromMicroSecondsSinceEpoch

If you are getting seconds in timestamp, then convert those seconds to milliseconds & create the DateTime object:

```
// Pass milliseconds to this constructor
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(milliseconds);

// Add 2 days to the dateTime object
dateTime.add(Duration(days: 2));
```